# Number of measurable maps $f: \{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I'm asked to find the number of measurable maps $f:\Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$,  where $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2 = \{1,2,3\}$.

Furthermore, we have that $\mathcal{F_1} = \mathcal{F_2} =\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$  and that $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F_1} ), (\Omega_2, \mathcal{F_2})$ are measurable spaces.

How can I proceed to find how many such maps exists? I'm not very good at measure theory since (by now) I've only seen a little and I don't know where I should start from.
Any hints?

Comment: Start by reviewing the definition of measurable maps, and spell out what it says in your particular case.

Comment: I agree with @WhatsUp ... This exercise is to get you to think about the definition.  It is not as helpful to you when others do the thinking for you.

Comment: The map is between elements of the sample space $\Omega_1$, i.e. $1$, $2$ and $3$ and $\Omega_2,$ composed of the same elements, *but* it has to preserve the structure of the "events" in the sigma algebra. I would guess that would force $1 \to 1,$ since $\{1\}$ is a subset in $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2.$ It wouldn't matter to this structure, though, if $2$ is mapped either to itself or $3;$ and the same applies to $2.$  The entire sample space $\{1,2,3\}$ has to map to itself; and so does $\emptyset.$

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate thank you very much, I think I understood now. I was using another definition for measurable before and I couldn't see the connection, but now it's clear.

Comment: Please verify. I was looking forward to a better answer, and hoping for confirmation or criticism. If you get a good explanation, can you post it as an edit or an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of measurable such maps is 15.

This is due to the fact that the preimage of any set in $\mathcal{F_2}$ must be in $\mathcal{F_1}$.
Let's analyse which cases satisfy such condition:

1. We fix $f(1)=1$, then

- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=3$
- $f(2)=1$ & $f(3)=1$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=3$

These are the only maps that satisfy the above condition when $ f(1)=1$, hence they are measurable.
Similarly:

2. $f(1)=2$, then

- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=3$
- $f(2)=1$ & $f(3)=1$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=3$

And

3. $f(1)=3$

- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=3$
- $f(2)=1$ & $f(3)=1$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=2$ & $f(3)=2$
- $f(2)=3$ & $f(3)=3$

The condition is always satisfied, therefore we have 3 situations having 5 measurable maps each, giving us a total of $$3\cdot5=15$$
measurable maps.